# Linear Combinations of spherical harmonics

Tags: spherical-harmonics

The familiar shapes of atomic orbitals arise from spherical harmonics $Y_{\nabla}^{m}$ or their linear combinations. Given:

$Y_1^1 = (\frac{3}{8 \pi})^{1/2} \sin \theta e^{i\phi}$

$Y_1^{-1} = (\frac{3}{8 \pi})^{1/2} \sin \theta e^{-i\phi}$

Show that the Linear combination $ I(\theta, \phi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2i}} (Y_1^1 - Y_1^{-1} ) $ yields a real function.

I found the linear combination of $Y_1^1 - Y_1^{-1} = (e^{i\phi} - e^{-i\phi} )^2 = 2i^2 \sin \phi $

How do I carry on from here?